Territorial Disputes in Halacha
If 2 countries are fighting over possession/ownership of land, and a person legally owns land in the disputed area according to one of the 2 countries, what would be the Halachic status of such land, in terms of Reshus HaRabim vs Reshus HaYachid?
For example, if someone owned land in Ukraine, wherein the Ukrainian government recognized that person's land as Reshus HaYachid, but the Russian government considered it Reshus HaRabim, what would be the true status of that land? Does it depend on military might or strategic foothold? Does might make right?
Or, in Heaven's perspective, are there true lines that demarcate the country's borders, irrespective of that country's own drawn borders? Like how the plagues that hit Mitzrayim revealed the true boundaries of the country, showing each side how much of the land wasn't actually considered Mitzrayim?

I don't think the designation affects Shabbos but it would be a bigger deal for the place name on gittin
